# Number of ways to go to goal vertex from start vertex

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I want to find out the number of ways to reach out to goal vertex from start vertex. The problem scenario is depicted as in the picture :

[image]

Here I want to go G vertex from S vertex. The only condition here is I can go up and right direction. DIrection diagonally/left/down is not allowed.

So keeping this condition in mind, what is the number of ways to go G vertex from S vertex?

### My trying :

I have figured out the no of ways are, $1^2+2^2+3^3+\ldots+(n-2)^2$. Is this correct?

Comment: can you explain how did you get the sum of squares formula?

Comment: hint: how many steps you need to go up (U), right (R)? combinations between them...UURURR, UUURRR....

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is a direct counting approach. Your path is a sequence of $n$ right steps (R's) and $m$ up steps (U's), with $m=n=3$. So you are asking how many strings can be made from 3 R's and 3 U's, which should be $\binom{6}{3}$.

Comment: So for n = 4 , the no of ways are $ \binom{8}{4} $ = 70  ?

Comment: Isn't it $n-1$ R's and $m-1$ U's?

Comment: @saulspatz thanks fixed